# Returning to the program that called pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am writing a game for my wife that is choose your own adventure style. Some of the adventures I want her to have to reach a score in a game in pygame, and return to the calling program after. I'm using pygame.quit() and then sys.exit() and it closes both the pygame, and the calling program. Is there a way to terminate the pygame, and return to the original program?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

`pygame.quit()` stops pygame and closes the window.

`sys.exit()` terminates the whole program.

If you are still in a loop you can break it by using `break`.